# spring mvc with facelets

Tags: java, spring-mvc, facelets

Is it possible to use facelets as view technology with Spring MVC? There is no mention about it in the official documentation, but I've heard that Facelets are very convenient and easy to use and I'd like to try it, I just don't know how...

Comment: I guess you meant Spring not springMVC? as springMVC and jsf are same layer frameworks. both for view layer.

Answer (score 3):

It might be worth trying Spring Web Flow, that comes with JSF2 (facelets) support:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/htmlsingle/spring-webflow-reference.html#whatsnew-swf-220

This link to the official documentation has a sample app integrating Spring WebFlow with faces.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to configure Spring MVC with Facelets. Check the solution here: https://github.com/acichon89/springmvcfacelets

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can. Rather very well you can have JSF frontend, Spring framework in the middle and probably Hibernate/webservice/JDBC in the backend.

For actions initiating from the JSF page which you migh expect to call the Spring in the backend, the controller in the JSF should call the Spring POJO and then onwards the it's all Spring to take care, you may have to pass on your bean from JSF to Spring bean.

Sometime back I found [this document](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2004/jw-0719-jsf.html), hope it helps you.